# Constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 3 were found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, broadleaf-commerce

I have an issue with running demo site (or admin) after configuring demo using [this link](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started/ide-setup/intellij-setup)

I got this error

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Constructor in
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration
>   required a single bean, but 3 were found:
>     - exporter: defined in class path resource [bl-common-applicationContext-mbeans.xml]
>     - blAutoDDLStatusExporter: defined in class path resource [bl-common-applicationContext-mbeans.xml]
>     - hibernateExporter: defined in class path resource [bl-common-applicationContext-mbeans.xml]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

How can I solve issue this issue?

Please note that I am using the latest Broadleaf Commerce version (5.2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

thanks for the answers, I managed to get it to run by removing the JMX property in the configuration properties from within IntelliJ.

1. click on Edit Configuration (from Run Menu)
2. deactivate the'Enable JMX Agent' (bottom right of dialog.
3. Apply and run

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are running the project from the newest version of IntelliJ, 2017.2. The workaround is to disable "Enable JMX Agent" in the run configuration for the boot project.

I opened an issue for this at https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/Issues/issues/1, this should be resolved in the next version of Broadleaf.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Qualifier annotation with the bean id you are trying to load,

@Qualifier("{bean_id_here}")

Comment: The beans are defined in XML so you can't use `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Also, the exception mentions that it happens within `SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration ` which is a Spring Boot Autoconfiguration class which you cannot modify.

Answer (score -1):

Annotate either

1. exporter
2. blAutoDDLStatusExporter
3. hibernateExporter

with `primary="true"` in your xml config files to let Spring know when bean should be the default for the Spring Admin JMX config or disable Spring Admin JMX auto-configuration by setting the `spring.application.admin=false` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: These beans are all defined within the Broadleaf core framework. Setting this property does not work because it is automatically added in the latest version of IntelliJ, 2017.2.